# Limit on number of Clusters supported by Cross cluster search (CCS) in Ealstic

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

Can I have a Architectural design where in we have around 100 clusters of Elastic.
Where in each cluster is basically a small set of Master Node and Data Nodes .

Using Cross Cluster Search if we send the search queries to a Cluster and let the query propagate from that cluster to other clusters for search result.

Is there a maximum number or a recommended number of Clusters which CCS supports ?

Does the CCS performance goes down with the increase of number of clusters beyond a certain threshold ?